# Google Colab でバージョン指定したインストールができない

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Google Colabでtensorflow(バージョン1.13.1)をインストールしたいのですが、以下のコードでうまくできません。昨日まではこれでインストールできていたのですが、突然できなくなってしまいました。

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
```

以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13.1 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.1
```

解決方法ございましたら、教えていただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 組み込まれているPython自身あるいは関連するモジュールの版数が新しくなってその版数のtensorflowをサポートしなくなっているのでは？ それらの版数を確かめてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: メッセージよく読みましよう。翻訳サイトもあるので "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow" で調べるとよいかも。選択肢も記されてます。Pythonのバージョン調べるなら `import sys; print(sys.version)` で出ます

Comment: お二人ともご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。頂いた回答を元に調べたところ、解決できそうです。ありがとうございます(_ _)

Answer (score 2):

[Colaboratory Release Notes](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/relnotes.ipynb)によると、2022/8/11に「Removed support for TensorFlow 1」と書かれています。TensorFlow 1.x系のサポートは終了のようです。2系に移行する必要があるでしょう。

参考までに下記記事ではtensorflow-gpu 1.15.2を使う方法が書かれています。※本日現在動作するかは当方では検証していません。

[Google ColabにおけるTensorFlow 1.x系のサポート終了への対応](https://qiita.com/katoyu_try1/items/0228870c41d9ac54e6e9)

[Did colab suspend tensorflow 1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215696/did-colab-suspend-tensorflow-1-x)